# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' but everthing is integer

Tags: flutter, dart

I know it seens duplicate, but its not, the answers from the other topics is nothing like i am facing here.

I really dont know whats going on, everthing is integer but stills aplies as string...

The problem occur on the FOR LOOP (if i print the somaModulos it shows the math correctly, only if i print inside the FOR LOOP, if i print outsite the FOR, it brings the errow below).

Everthing later dont execute because the problem "type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

```
      var textModulos = modulosNecessarios.toString();

      int somaModulos = 0;
      void recalcularModulos() {
        print(modulosConfig);
        print(int.parse(modulosConfig[0][0]) * int.parse(modulosConfig[0][1])); //THIS WORKS

        for (var i = 0; i < modulosConfig.length; i++) { // THIS DONT WORK
          somaModulos +=
              int.parse(modulosConfig[i][0]) * int.parse(modulosConfig[i][1]);
        }

        /*
        setState(() {
          textModulos = (modulosNecessarios - somaModulos).toString();
        });
        */
      }
```

The results of the prints:

1º

```
[[20, 3, colonial, retrato], [0, 0, colonial, retrato]]
```

2º

```
60
```

Comment: Is modulosNecessarios really int?

Comment: What are the data types of `modulosNecessarios` and `modulosConfig` ?

Comment: Why declare textModulos as a var when you explicitly assign a string to it, and why declare i as a var when you explicitly assign an int to it that you increment? I know there's a lot of debate around the use of var, but type ambiguity can be problematic. Which leads me to wonder, seeing as we can't see in your code where modulosNecessarios is declared, if it isn't a string.

Comment: the setState is irrelevant here, because is the loop where the problem is... also, yes, the modulosNecessarios and modulosConfig are both integer... i will update with a example that works

Comment: You say that "everything is [an] integer", but some things (e.g. `int.parse`) expect `String`s, not `int`s.

Comment: in my array, its a integer, but if i remove that, another problem occur... its still aplies as a string, in the first print i show the math working, in the loop does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seens that the array type values changed on the textField onChange.

Even the text input type was a number, it changes to string if i put it on the onChange method, i was not paying attetion to that (i am new to dart).

The items in the list was always creating with int values, but it changed to string in the middle of the process...

```
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Quantidade de módulos"),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                controller: _controllerQnt,
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                    modulosConfig[itemUtilized][0] = value;
                  });
                },
```

To make it work, i changed the array incremention from:

```
modulosConfig.insert(indexStart, [0, 0, 'colonial', 'retrato']);
```

To:

```
modulosConfig.insert(indexStart, ['0', '0', 'colonial', 'retrato']);
```

Or change the TextField onChange method integer.

I choose to change the incremention to all string and then parse it on the FOR LOOP.